# Popover content size on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, popover

I am working on a iOS app using mainly `SceneKit`. I am creating the whole layout inside Interface Builder. I also have a button in the main view and from it I created a segue. I set the segue kind to Popover.

It is linked to another **subclass of UIViewController**. This again contains some controls. When I run this on the **iPad, it shows as a popover, and it even changes size depending on the Content Size** (set on the presented view controller in IB again).

However, when I run this **on the iPhone it always shows as a fullscreen view**. I know that in fact it should, and it can be easily overridden by using the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and setting the style to None.

But I would instead like it to present modally, but not cover the whole screen. I tried setting `preferredContentSize` inside the presented `UIViewController` subclass. That didn't do anything. Setting the Content Size in the IB also doesn't seem to work. **I would like to set the height to maybe half the parents.**

I am targeting iOS 8.0 and using latest Xcode. I know there are tons of questions about popover size on SO, but none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: You CAN NOT do that in iPhone.

Comment: That means I will need two different storyboards? In the one for iPad I present the view using popover and in one for iPhone I could for example embed the view inside View Container (and resize that to desired dimensions)?